# Insert local video in CKEditor

Tags: php, ckeditor, wysiwyg, file-browser, video-embedding

I need a plugin for CKEditor that will enable a user to embed a video that is located on the server. I added the oEmbed plugin, but that only allows the user to embed a video from sources like YouTube, Vimeo, etc.

Basically, we have a site that allows an administrator to customize a page using the CKEditor WYSIWYG editor. There's a directory on the server that holds video files. We want the administrator to be able to browse the videos in that directory, and pick one to embed in the editor.

Is this even possible? I've looked around at file uploaders, but they just browse the user's local machine, not the server. I'm a bit stuck figuring out how to accomplish this.

Comment: will this work? http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload

Answer (score 1):

Try html5video plugin or make your own http://ckeditor.com/addon/html5video